# How to get a generic type from a list of types

Tags: c#, list, generics

I would like to pass a list of interfaces to a method as a parameter.
Then I would like to iterate through this list to call a generic method.
How can I do this?

```
//the interfaces
public interface IView{}
public interface IView1 : IView {}
public interface IView2 : IView {}
//the forms
public partial class MyView1 : Form, IView1 {}
public partial class MyView2 : Form, IView2 {}

//this works
var myOpenForm = GetForm<IView1>();

//this doesn't work
var myList = new List<T> { IView1, IView2 }; <-- ERROR: IView1 is a type, which is not valid in the given context
var myOpenForm = GetFirstForm(myList);

//find the first form open of the specified types
public static T GetFirstForm(List<T> viewTypes)
{
    foreach (var myType in viewTypes)
    {
        var form = GetForm<myType>(); <-- ERROR: myType is a variable but is used like a type
        if(form != null)
        {
            return form;
        }
    }
}

//find form of type T if it is open in the application
public static T GetForm<T>()
{
    foreach (var form in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        if (form is T)
        {
            return (T)form;
        }
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

I can get rid of the first error declaring `myList` by replacing `List<T>` with `List<Type>` in the method signature, but then I don't know how I would be able to call the inner method with T instead of Type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store types. You can store objects. You can get an object that contain's a type's metadata using `typeof` or `GetType()`. Also, type parameters are fixed at compile time, so you can't populate them from a variable at run time.

So instead of this

```
var myList = new List<T> { IView1, IView2 };
```

You need this

```
var myList new List<Type> { typeof(IView1), typeof(IView2) };
```

And for your `GetFirstForm` call you need something more like this:

```
public static Form GetFirstForm(List<Type> viewTypes)
{
    foreach (var myType in viewTypes)
    {
        var form = GetForm(myType);
        if(form != null)
        {
            return form;
        }
    }
}

public static Form GetForm(Type type)
{
    foreach (var form in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        if (type.IsAssignableFrom(form.GetType()))
        {
            return form;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Resharper is telling me to use `type.IsInstanceOfType(form)`, rather than `type.IsAssignableFrom(form.GetType())` but it compiles. Also the purpose of getting the form is to call a method on IView - so I'll have to cast the result, which is unavoidable I suppose